# three levels of parenthesis/quoting in shell snippets in tcsh?

Tags: perl, sh, quotes, tcsh

I'm using tcsh; I want to run some snippet from sh on the command line, which itself contains a perl snippet, which contains some strings that are to be printed.

This results in three levels of parentheses, but there are only two available — " and '.

Is there a way around?

`tcsh# sh -c 'while (true); do mtr --order "SRL BGAWV M" …; hping --icmp-ts --count 12 … | perl -ne '... if (/tsrtt=(\d+)/) {print $0,"\t"…}' ; done'`

Comment: A nice trick when you run into problems with quoting is to simply put all your Perl code into a file, and then replace the `-e ' ... '` code with the file name, e.g. `| perl -n script.pl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include a single quote inside of single quotes, use `'\''`. e.g.

```
perl -ne'... print $0, "\t" ...'
```

becomes

```
sh -c '... | perl -ne'\''... print $0, "\t" ...'\'''
```

---

In this particular case, an alternative is to replace

```
perl -ne'... print $0, "\t" ...'
```

with

```
perl -ne"... print \$0, qq{\t} ..."
```

so you'd get

```
sh -c '... | perl -ne"... print \$0, qq{\t} ..."'
```

---

I'd just write the whole thing in Perl

```
perl -e'
    while (1) {
       system("mtr", "--order", "SRL BGAWV M");

       open(my $pipe, "-|", "hping", "--icmp-ts", "--count", "12");
       while (<$pipe>) {
          ...
       }
    }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `q/../` for single quotes and `qq/.../` for double quotes within your Perl code.

For instance, `print $0, qq/\t/`

Comment: great stuff!  but it doesn't seem to work:  if I continue using single quotes for `sh`, and change to double quotes for `perl -ne`, then `sh` doesn't like the perl stuff; if I reverse, then `tcsh` doesn't like `$0`.  Any way to refer to `$0` without `$`? :)

Comment: Specifically, I also have stuff like `($o,$r,$t)=($1,$2,$3);`, too.

Comment: Then you should escape the dollars, like `\$`. Use `echo` in place of `perl` to see what string you are actually passing.

Comment: Well, `tcsh` doesn't let you escape stuff like `$0`, except for using `'`.  If I go the other way, then I'm getting some kind of weird parenthesis error from something within: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "(,"`.

Comment: OK, I guess I'm getting that error, because variables have a default value of empty in `sh`, and that's what perl is getting.

Comment: So, yeah, escaping `$0` as `\$0` works once in `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is doing a big and long `echo`, with a few arguments, all escaped with `'`, where the actual literal `'` is gathered from the result of executing `printf "'"`, and piping this whole `echo` to `sh`, instead of passing the string as an argument directly to sh.

This actually seems somewhat easier, because it doesn't involve escaping the whole perl snippet, basically, but only escaping the two `'` that are used for `perl -ne`.

tcsh# echo 'while (true); do mtr --order "SRL BGAWV M" …; hping --icmp-ts --count 12 … | perl -ne' `printf "'"` '... if (/tsrtt=(\d+)/) {print $0,"\t"…}' `printf "'"` '; done' | sh